# Need reference for ideals and representations of $C_0(X,A)$

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, ideals

Let $A$ be $C^{\ast}$- Algebra and $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $C_{0}(X,A)$ be the set of all continuous functions from $X$ to $A$ vanishing at infinity. Define $f^{\ast}(t)={f(t)}^{\ast}$ (for $t\in X$). It is well known that $C_0(X,A)$ is $C^{\ast}-$ Algebra.

> What’s  known about ideals and representations of $C_0(X,A)$?

My guess is that it must be related with ideals and representations of $A$. Can someone give a reference or some ideas?

P.S: The same question was first posted on MSE but unfortunately I dint not get any answer so I am posting it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $x \in X$ let $I_x$ be a closed ideal of $A$. Then the set of $f \in C_0(X,A)$ satisfying $f(x) \in I_x$ for all $x$ is clearly an ideal of $C_0(X,A)$, and it shouldn't be too hard to show that every closed ideal has this form.

I assume this is "well known" but I don't have a reference.

As for representations, use the fact that $C_0(X,A)$ is $*$-isomorphic to the C*-algebra tensor product $C_0(X) \otimes A$. (Since $C_0(X)$ is abelian there is only one tensor product.) Thus the representations of $C_0(X,A)$ correspond to pairs of representations of $C_0(X)$ and $A$ on the same Hilbert space and whose ranges commute.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know about representations too?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want in regards to representations ...

Comment: I am mainly interested in seeing connection between representations of $A$ and of $C0(X,A)$.

Comment: Well, if $\pi$ is a representation of $A$ and $x \in X$ then $f \mapsto \pi(f(x))$ is a representation of $C_0(X,A)$. What else are you looking for?

Comment: What about the converse i.e.all representations of $C0(X,A)$ are of the form you mentioned?

Comment: @MathLover have you tried to work this out for yourself using the connections between ideals, homomorphisms and representations? It seems that Nik has already given you most of what you need to proceed

Comment: @YemonChoi I added that part of my answer after Math Lover asked the question in their comment.